# PHP change active directory user password with a admin username and password

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to change password for a user using PHP using a admin user and password rather than the old password of the account that's being changed. The only thing I was able to find was the code below but it seems COM is only for windows machines and my PHP scripts are running on a linux machine on the network.

```
$ADSI = new COM("LDAP:");
$user = $ADSI->OpenDSObject("LDAP://".$server."/".$newuser_dn, $adminuser, $adminpassword, 1);
$user->SetPassword($newuser_password);
$user->SetInfo();
```

Anyone able to tell me how I can do this using another method without using COM?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this works on Windows hosts only. You may use the [Oracle libraries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php).